# Dynamically creating a button with a click handler in Windows/UWP/C++

Tags: windows, uwp, click, c++-cx

I've got the following code in a method that creates a button and adds it to a listview. However, its not clear how to add a click event handler to the button when you are coding in C++ rather than c#.

```
Button ^ nb = ref new Button();
nb->Content = ref new Platform::String(name.c_str());

nb->Click  // what goes here???

DeviceList->Items->Append(nb);
```

Illumination? Thank you.

Comment: `Button ^ nb = ref new Button();` Is not valid C++ syntax. Since you tagged UWP, aren't you developing in [tag:C++-CX], instead of C++?

Comment: I'm rather new to the windows development arena. I had no idea what their extension to C++ was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to add a click event handler to the button when you are coding in C++

You need create a new RoutedEventHandler instance that bind `OnClick` callback method then use `+=` combine `Click` event. Certainly, you could also press <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcuts after typed `+=` character.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Button ^btn = ref new Button();
    btn->Content = "TestBtn";
    btn->Click += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventHandler(this, &App5::MainPage::OnClick);
    RootLayout->Children->Append(btn);
}

void App5::MainPage::OnClick(Platform::Object ^sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs ^e)
{
    throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
}
```